# Simple Rails validation issue with non-user defined inputs

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Background**

- I'm using the **acts_as_list** gem in a rails app
- my posts table has a **position** column
- position is assigned in a before_create callback in my model:

This is the code for my Post model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base    
  acts_as_list
  before_create :set_position
  attr_accessible :title, :description, :category_id
  validates :position, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true 

  protected
    def set_position
      self.position = Post.all.size + 1
    end
end
```

**My Problem:**
I don't want users to be able to set the position, so I've removed the position field from the Post form.  When I submit a new post, the validation fails, and I'm told that position can't be blank.

I realise that my validation is failing because the user is not inputting the position themselves, but I have set the position in the before_filter, so how can I get rails to use that information when it is performing the validation?

**Bonus Question**
The form submits when I remove the validation, but I was wondering why this works because I don't pass **position** to attr_accessible?  I pass a number of other symbols to it like so:  `attr_accessible :title, :description, :category_id` but I don't pass `:position`. Is there likely to be any problems there? Should position be attr_protected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question

```
before_validation :set_position, :on => :create
```

Bonus question.
You probably got mass assigment warrning (check your logs)
When you remove validation rails dont return any error on `:position` so they save what was in `attr_accesible` (probably the position will be null in DB)